# Error while trying to execute a binary file whit zsh alias

Tags: binary, zsh, alias

i got a binary file in a specific directory and I was trying to make an alias in my .zshrc file to execute the binary file. And I was getting this error message when I try to run it:

```
jupiter
zsh: can't open input file: /home/josh/Documents/cc3/images/bin/./jupiter
```

I wrote the alias like this:

```
alias jupiter="zsh ~/Documents/cc3/images/bin/./jupiter"
```

Then I wrote the command `omz reload` to apply changes to the .zshrc file, but I'm still getting the same error.

Could anyone help me and let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `/home/josh`. A director named `~` does not exist, and tilde expansion does not occur between double quotes. The expansion only occurs at the **start**  of an **unquoted word**.

```
alias jupiter="zsh $HOME/Documents/cc3/images/bin/jupiter"
```

Alternatively you can use a function:

```
jupiter() {
  zsh ~/Documents/cc3/images/bin/jupiter
}
```